# this.state.item.id is undefned. react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

After parsing some individual result from an API, I'm running into this issue.

I assign the value to my array:

```
this.setState({
   item: responseJson.items,
});
```

But when I try to render one of its results in the view nothing is rendered and in the log it appears as `undefined`.

What I try to do is: `{this.state.item.id}`

An example of the json I get:

```
{"items":[{"id":"17228","strItem":"Toy", etc. etc.
```

How to render that `id`?

on the render
`<Text>{this.state.item.id}</Text>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: also add the render function

Comment: `this.state.item` is an array

Comment: You should access the element you want by using `this.state.item[i].id` where `i` is the index of the element.

Comment: `this.state.item[0].id`

Comment: @MoshFeu by doing that I get a `undefined is not an object`

Comment: Please show more of your code, specifically where is `responseJson.items` being defined and given a value? My guess is the `responseJson.items` IS undefined/empty array when it reaches your render function which takes place after the component mounts, which could have happened before your API response returned with a result... In addition to improperly accessing the item objects as stated by everyone else

Comment: read on how to get item from array here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @segFault its already shown where, please pay attention.

Comment: No, you don't have the code I am referring to in your question. You simply gave us the value you expect to be there... but as I said, you probably are trying to access that data BEFORE it is available to you.

Comment: It DOES get a value, I've console logged it, it does return the whole JSON for the SINGLE item.

Comment: Sorry, item**s** - `this.state.items[0].id`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct solution was to map it.

Solution code:

```
{this.state.fontLoaded && this.state.item.map(it => {
return (
<Text>ID: {it.id}</Text>
)
})}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `this.state.item` is an array.

If you want to get item you should use `[]` syntax.

```js
const firstItem = this.state.item[0];
const firstItemId = firstItem.id;
```

If you want to get an array item by `id`:

```js
const desiredItem = this.state.item.find(item => item.id === desiredId);
```

Checking:

```js
if (Array.isArray(this.state.item) && this.state.item.length > 0) {
  console.log(this.state.item[0]);
}
```

Comment: If I use `this.state.item[0].id` I get a `undefined is not an object`.

Comment: @DanielLogvin I this it's because you don't have your item immediately. Try to use `if` statement.
I'll update answer

Comment: It's probably defaulted to an empty array... we need more info in your question @DanielLogvin

Comment: I added length checking